# Tinymce editor generating html code for text color and background color changing but not sending

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using Tinymce editor for my Laravel application. Everything is working fine but getting a little bit problem when I'm changing color or background color of any text.

[image: Trying to do the following]
It's generating html but not sending when I'm submit
[image]
**The initialization is following:**

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '#description',
        extended_valid_elements : 'span',
        verify_html: true,
        height: 400,
        theme: 'modern',
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
            'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample | mybutton',
        image_advtab: true,
        image_title: true,
        image_caption: true,
        relative_urls: false,
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "forecolor,backcolor,fontselect,fontsizeselect",

        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' },
        ],
    });
```

When i'm debugging the output it showing me the following: 
[image]

Comment: If you inspect the text with the DOM Inspector, does the HTML have the correct inline style attributes there? Or is a CSS stylesheet handling the rules?

Comment: yes it generates the inline css. But when I'm submitting it then it is skipping the inline CSS. i'm updating my question. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: If you use TinyMCE's api to grab the data, does it show that way?  Something like `window.tinymce.get('myTextEditorID').getContent()`

Comment: If the data is correct in TinyMCE but not there after you submit the form then I bet you have some code that is processing the HTML during the save and its removing those inline styles.  The fact that it shows correctly in TinyMCE would tell me that TinyMCE is not removing the styles.

Comment: All inline CSS is contained during save. Only color changing is not saved. I can't identify where is going wrong :) @MichaelFromin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution: It works if I set

```
tinymce.init({
     extended_valid_elements: true,
     //or
     extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target=_blank]',
});
```